# a better version of the following code (python)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, lambda, zip

so here i have the following peice of code

```
def u_id(_id = '6397' , uid = '97492035'):
  n = _id if _id != None else '5000'
  try:
    return "".join(list(map(lambda x: str(x[0] + x[1])[-1], list(zip(list(map(lambda x: int(x), n)), list(map(lambda x: int(x), uid[4:])))))))
  except ValueError:
    return "none"
```

to be honest, this looks rather unnecessary. the way this function works is that this takes the uid and the _id provided and returns '6119'. basically i cant figure out the way this code works from the way it is coded. is there possibly a different and less puzzling way to code this? or if not explain how this function works. thank you.

Comment: I'm not really gonna bother trying to answer this, but I want to comment on a few things in this code that made me laugh. list(zip()) when zip() returns a list...return "none" in a language with None, using 2 space indents and repeated lambdas in a single line. Is this from an obfuscated code competition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your function could be simplified like this:

```
"".join(str(int(x) + int(y))[-1] for x, y in zip(_id, uid[4:]))
```

But for given parameters it's returning `'8322'`, not `'6119'`

Answer (score 1):

The function is *really* obfuscated, but it doesn't do what you think it does. You say it returns '6119' however if I run the following code

```
def u_id(_id = '6397' , uid = '97492035'):
  n = _id if _id != None else '5000'
  try:
    return "".join(list(map(lambda x: str(x[0] + x[1])[-1], list(zip(list(map(lambda x: int(x), n)), list(map(lambda x: int(x), uid[4:])))))))
  except ValueError:
    return "none"

print u_id()
```

The output for me is `8322`

I should also add that the code is using 2-space indentation, which is not very orthodox, it's better to use 4-space.

I won't solve this problem for you (it looks quite tedious, whoever wrote this was not a fan of clarity!) But I'll tell you how to solve it - you need to get each of those inner functions, put them on their own line and print out the output of each of them.

Comment: oh the values that i put in might not have been the right ones. normally this is called from another function

Comment: What is it *supposed* to do then? This deep level of nesting is extremely hard to debug, especially when the point of the function is not known.

Comment: it returns a value based on the two numbers, _id and uid

Comment: the returned value is then used in another function